# One commit back from FETCH_HEAD

Tags: git

When looking at the latest git commits, I know you can do git log -1..HEAD in order to look at the last commit before HEAD. What I'd like to do is along the same lines,  but rather than looking one back from HEAD, I'd like to do it from FETCH_HEAD. Is there a way denoting this in the git log command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git log FETCH_HEAD~12..FETCH_HEAD
```

this will show the latest 12 commits from FETCH_HEAD